# Zener diode electric field working principle

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics

Well I recently saw a video from khan academy about zener diodes.This video was suggested by another member of Stack Exchange Physics who I thank him very much . But I didnt understand some things:Here is what I get:Zener diodes operate just like the normal diodes , except the fact that they are heavilier doped , their zero bias depletion region is narrower and they are not ruined for voltages over their breakdown voltage in reverse bias.But some things dont make sense . The video says that a Zener diode has a very strong electric field ( stronger than the normal diodes) . But how is that possible . Donor and acceptor ions are immobile are stationary so it is electrostatics. In reverse bias the potential  of the electrostatic field must be equal to the potential of the battery.Why zener diodes have a larger electric field than normal diodes since their potential in reverse bias when they counteract the flow of electrons is the same?

Comment: The depletion region is narrower, so more volts per meter for the field (given the same potential across the region as you expect).

Comment: Oh yes I am so stupid ! Thank you Jon. Goodnight.